# The Go program isn't reading the second input from the user

Tags: go, debugging, input, sleep

I'm writing an 8 ball program and when I run it, it waits for the first question and reads it but when it asks if the user wants to ask another question, the program doesn't read the input and closes.
Here is the code:

```
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Bene, cominciamo")
        for i := 0; i == 0; {
            fmt.Println("Scrivi qui sotto la tua domanda")
            fmt.Print("> ")
            var answer string
            fmt.Scan(&answer)
            if answer != "" {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
                randomguess := rand.Intn(20)
                switch randomguess {
                case 0: fmt.Println("Si, certo")
                case 1: fmt.Println("Non lo so, ma sei uno scemo")
                case 2: fmt.Println("No, non dovresti")
                case 3: fmt.Println("Assolutamente si, cazzo")
                case 4: fmt.Println("Sono una palla, che cazzo ne so?")
                case 5: fmt.Println("No hahaha")
                case 6: fmt.Println("SI, perché no?")
                case 7: fmt.Println("Chiedimelo più tardi, quando sono meno impegnato")
                case 8: fmt.Println("Te lo posso dire tranquillamente: NO")
                case 9: fmt.Println("Si anche se non me ne potrebbe fregar di meno")
                case 10: fmt.Println("Non lo so, ritenta")
                case 11: fmt.Println("Fanculo, sai già che è NO")
                case 12: fmt.Println("Si.")
                case 13: fmt.Println("Non ti saprei dire adesso")
                case 14: fmt.Println("La mia risposta è no")
                case 15: fmt.Println("Si, senza dubbio")
                case 16: fmt.Println("No, letteralmente no")
                case 17: fmt.Println("Certo")
                case 18: fmt.Println("NO???")
                case 19: fmt.Println("Secondo me si")
                case 20: fmt.Println("Mai, ignorante")
                }
            }
            time.Sleep(3500 * time.Millisecond)
            fmt.Println("Vuoi chiedere qualcos'altro alla 8ball?")
            fmt.Print("> ")
            var newanswer string
            fmt.Scan(&newanswer)
            yeschecker := strings.Contains(newanswer, "si")
            nochecker := strings.Contains(newanswer, "no")
            if yeschecker {
                continue //restarts the loop
            } else if nochecker {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("Ok, chiudo il programma")
                time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
                os.Exit(2)
            } else {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("Ok, chiudo il programma")
                time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
                os.Exit(2)
            }
        }
```

Sorry if the program is in Italian though.

Comment: Could you add a English translation if possible? Also please post the sample input for which the failure is occurring.

Comment: Hey, I ran it. It's working perfectly fine. Please double-check!

Comment: Don't worry guys I worked it out